# Video Not Always Showing Up On Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jwplayer

I have a weird bug on my website that I need help fixing...

This is a brand new Wordpress installation with the Carton theme, and the JWPlayer plugin.

Here is my site: http://kenai.asap.um.maine.edu/maine_journal_dev

If you click on the post titled "**A Hobby Takes Flight: Observing Avian Activity using RC Aircraft**" then you will be taken to the post for that page.

You will notice that there is a spot for the video but the video does not load. However, it will load if the page is refreshed.

Therefore, the bug is: **The video does not load when directed from the homepage, however; if refreshed once on the page the video will load**. (It might load, but it usually doesn't)

Can anybody tell me what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you noticing this in? What OS?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the bug in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome on Mac OS.

Comment: Can you paste your javascript code and HTML?

Comment: Of what page? I have one big Wordpress installation.

Comment: I see  [wowza name=AllainVideo_1.mp4], is this some custom Wowza plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue occurs when the video is loaded before theme.js starts executing.

if you have access to theme.js I would change the following function:

```
all_videos.each( function() {
    var video = $(this);

    if ( video.parents( 'object' ).length )
        return;

    if ( ! video.prop( 'id' ) )
        video.attr( 'id', 'rvw' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 999999 ) );

    video
        .wrap( '<div class="responsive-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: ' + ( video.attr( 'height' ) / video.attr( 'width' ) * 100 ) + '%" />' )
        .removeAttr( 'height' )
        .removeAttr( 'width' );
} );
```

to:

```
all_videos.each( function() {
    var video = $(this);

    if ( video.parents( 'object' ).length || video.parents('#jwplayer-0_wrapper').length)
        return;

    if ( ! video.prop( 'id' ) )
        video.attr( 'id', 'rvw' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 999999 ) );

    video
        .wrap( '<div class="responsive-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: ' + ( video.attr( 'height' ) / video.attr( 'width' ) * 100 ) + '%" />' )
        .removeAttr( 'height' )
        .removeAttr( 'width' );
} );
```

As a very quick and dirty fix. The main issue is that the jwplayer is conflicting with the theme.js functionality which seems to try to wrap all object elements in a responsive container

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly.